# Batch compress mp3 while retaining file and directory structure to new target

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, mp3, compression

I have a master directory of music which is organised using subdirectories. My new (cheap) MP3 only holds 8GB so I wish to make a reduced version of my music with a lower bitrate.

Is there a free program which will compress MP3 to say 128 from a source location to a different target location while retaining directory structure and files names?

I wish to point the application to the root of my music and have it compress all subdirectories and files for me.

Comment: Which operating system? And which source format (I guess mp3 but it is not explicitly stated)?

Comment: sorry. have added those details. Wish to compress existing mp3 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LameXP](http://lamexp.sourceforge.net/) can batch encode mp3s from a location and then output them to another location, preserving the directory structure.

The option you will be wanting is "Prepend relative source file path to output file" on the Output Directory tab of the application.

Its a little bit wierd in that it actually sticks folders for the files full path in (so if encode from C:\Users\Me\Music and output to C:\Users\Me\Music2, you'll end up with C:\Users\Me\Music2\Users\Me\Music as the effective output folder) but it does the job, and preserves directory structure.

Comment: Nice one. Thanks for the heads up on the directory issue. No problem to move the files after.